# Replace switch statement with a map (for different data-types)

Tags: java, generics, switch-statement, refactoring

I am trying to replace the following switch statement with a map.

```
public ObjGeometry geometry(final Iterable<String> lines) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    final List<Vector3f> vertices = Lists.newArrayList();
    final List<Vector2f> textures = Lists.newArrayList();
    final List<Vector3f> normals = Lists.newArrayList();
    final List<Face> faces = Lists.newArrayList();

    for (final String line : lines) {
      final List<String> lineElements = Arrays.asList(line.split(" "));
      final String token = lineElements.get(0);

      switch (token) {
        case VERTEX:
          final Vector3f vertex = createVertex(lineElements);
          vertices.add(vertex);
          break;
        case TEXTURE:
          final Vector2f texture = createTexture(lineElements);
          textures.add(texture);
          break;
        case NORMAL:
          final Vector3f normal = createNormal(lineElements);
          normals.add(normal);
          break;
        case FACES:
          final Face face = createFace(lineElements);
          faces.add(face);
          break;
      }
    }
    return ObjGeometry.from(vertices, textures, normals, faces);
  }
```

The methods `#createVertex`,`#createTexture`,`#createNormal`and `#createFace` transforming a string to a special dataType (Vector2f, Vector3f or Face)

What i want to do is... to build a Map `Map<TOKEN, Parser>`, so I can iterate over that map and call the right parser for a special token (btw. TOKEN is a String like "v", "vt", "vn", or "f").

What i have is:

- abstract class`ExtractVector3f` with method `#vectorFrom(List<String>)` - can transform a `List<String>` to `Vector3f`
- abstract class`ExtractVector2f` with method `#vectorFrom(List<String>)` - can transform a `List<String>` to `Vector2f`
- abstract class`ExtractFace` with method `#faceFrom(List<String>)` - can transform a `List<String>` to `Face`
- an interface `LineParser`

  ```
  public interface LineParser<T> {
    T apply(final List<String> lineElements);
  }
  ```
- a class to parse a vertex

  ```
  public class ParseVertex extends ExtractVector3f implements LineParser<Vector3f> {
    @Override
    public Vector3f apply(final List<String> lineElements) {
      return vectorFrom(lineElements);
    }
  }
  ```
- a class to parse a normal

  ```
  public class ParseNormal extends ExtractVector3f implements LineParser<Vector3f> {
    @Override
    public Vector3f apply(final List<String> lineElements) {
      return vectorFrom(lineElements);
    }
  }
  ```
- a class to parse a texture

  ```
  public class ParseTexture extends ExtractVector2f implements LineParser<Vector2f> {
    @Override
    public Vector2f apply(final List<String> lineElements) {
      return vectorFrom(lineElements);
    }
  }
  ```
- and a class to parse a face

  ```
  public class ParseFace extends ExtractFaces implements LineParser<Face> {
    @Override
    public Face apply(final List<String> lineElements) {
      return faceFrom(lineElements);
    }
  }
  ```

The next step would be to build the map... something like

```
    Map<String, LineParser> parsers = Maps.newHashMap();
        parsers.put("v", new ParseVertex());
        parsers.put("vt", new ParseTexture());
        parsers.put("vn", new ParseNormal());
        parsers.put("f", new ParseFace());
```

**But** now i get in trouble. LineParser in this map is a raw type and raw-types should be avoid.

**My Question is:**
How can i build a map, with POJOs in it - which return different data-types on the method which is defined via Interface?

Comment: Why do you want to iterate ? The point of a map is a fact access to its elements, and iterating over a collection is not fast.

Comment: You could declare the `Map` using an unbounded wildcard: `Map<String, LineParser<?>> parsers`, but then you'll need an unsafe cast when retrieving data.

Comment: @Dici Well.... i think iterate is not the right word. In the end I must parse a line which starts with a token... I think i will call `get(token)` on the map to get the right parser.

Comment: Well.. assuming i have a method which will return `parsers.get(token)` - what must be the return type of this method (when i use wildcard)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not do this, actually. Even if the map is a good idea, done this way you lose the exact type of the objects you build. What are you gonna do with them after that ? How do you know to which collection adding them ? You can't, unless the parsers have access to all collections to pick the right one. This suggests the parsers should know your main class, or methods of this class.

I would just use lambdas :

```
Consumer<List<String>> handleTexture = args -> textures.add(parseTexture(args))
Consumer<List<String>> handleVertice = args -> vertices.add(parseVertice(args))
...
Map<String, Consumer<List<String>> handlers = new HashMap<>();
handlers.put("vf", handleTexture);
handlers.put("v", handleVertice);
...

for (final String line : lines) {
      final List<String> lineElements = Arrays.asList(line.split(" "));
      final String token = lineElements.get(0);
      handlers.get(token).accept(lineElements.sublist(1, lineElements.size()));)
}
```

If you want to do it with Java 7 it is syntactically less nice, but the principle is the same. Create a interface like `Consumer` with a method `accept` (you can change all the names if you want to make the class more specific to your project, like `Parser` and `parse`, just keep the same signature for the method) :

```
public class Consumer<T> {
     public void accept(T t);
}
```

Then, in your code

```
Consumer<List<String>> handleTexture = new Consumer<List<String>>() { 
    @Override
    public void accept(List<String> args) {
        textures.add(parseTexture(args));
    }
}
```

The rest is just the same !

Comment: Well i've have no knowledge about lambda-expression.. so i've to read. Your answer is very interesting, and i will try it today (later, after work). Only for completness... is there a solution with Java 7?

Comment: @SleepyX667 I completed my answer and fixed some mistakes in it